# Ancorar um TR é possível?

Tags: javascript, html, link, table

É possível por fora de um elemento `tr` linkar algum endereço como abaixo?

```html
<a href="www.enderecodesejado.com.br"></a>
```

Se não é possível, o JavaScript resolveria isto ou é melhor esquecer?

Tenho a seguinte tabela como mostrado na imagem abaixo, e queria que quando o usuário clicasse numa linha fosse direcionado para um endereço X.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infelizmente não existe nenhum construção específica para isso. Você terá que fazer *"na mão"*.

Fica relativamente simples fazer com jQuery e *data-* attributes*. Exemplo:

JavaScript:

```js
$('tr').click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-href');
});
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Empresa
    </th>
    <th>
      CEO
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-href="http://www.google.com/">
    <td>
       Google
    </td>
    <td>
      Larry Page
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-href="http://www.yahoo.com/">
    <td>
        Yahoo!
    </td>
    <td>
      Marissa Mayer
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-href="http://www.microsoft.com/">
    <td>
        Microsoft
    </td>
    <td>
      Steve Ballmer
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Exemplo mais completo (incluindo estilo)](http://jsfiddle.net/d4q4U/).

Comment: +1 Pelo "(incluindo estilo)"

Comment: Verdade @Zignd! Veio completo a resposta. Valeu @talles

Comment: Para evitar comportamentos inesperados é recomendável incluir o `[data-href]` no seletor: `$('tr[data-href]').click(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Sim é possivel com javascript. 
Inserir links entre table e tr não é sintaxe correcta, por isso a via é mesmo javascript.

Pode adicionar um "event handler" que procura cliques dentro das linhas da tabela. Quando acontecer um clique vai buscar o link dessa linha e abre-o.

Exemplo com jQuery:

```
var linhaTabela = $('table tr');
linhaTabela.on('click', function (event) {
    var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href')
    link && window.location = link;
});
```

### [**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CRPU4/2/show/)

---

Se não houver link dentro da linha como eu referí no exemplo acima, pode atribuir via seu php a informação do link num campo `data-`, aí sim na linha da tabela.

Assim o meu exemplo é

html

```
<tr data-href="http://www.google.com">
```

javascript

```
var linhaTabela = $('table tr');
linhaTabela.on('click', function (event) {
    var link = $(this).data('href');
    link && window.location = link;
});
```

### [**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4nejK/2/show/)

Comment: o link seria por fora da `tr`.

Comment: @Luitame, como por fora? Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Sim! Eu tenho uma `table` correto? Tenho um loop em PHP para imprimir linhas (`tr`) e por fora dessa `tr` queria colocar um link. Exemplo: `<table> <tbody> <a href='painel.php?spv=nav/userview&usr=1'><tr> Conteudo </tr> </a> </tbody></table>`

Comment: Fazer como que a linha (`tr`) se torne um hyperlink, certo?

Comment: correto!!! @Zignd

Answer (score 3):

Se você embrulhar a `<tr>` num `<a>`, seu HTML se tornará inválido. Sugiro que você coloque a URL num attributo `data`, e use um código muito semelhante [ao do Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1882/#1883) para navegar para o destino.

**HTML**

```html
<table>
    <tr data-url="http://www.enderecodesejado.com.br">
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    if(url) window.location = url;
});
```

Comment: Obrigado ai pela força...

Comment: +1 porque a resposta é util, correcta e porque quero [uma medalha](http://br.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship) :)

Comment: Hehe, obrigado @Sergio. Eu tenho o hábito de votar em respostas concorrentes no SO, e já aviso que essa medalha demora um pouco para chegar.

Comment: hehe, sim, por isso é bom ganhar o hábito cedo :P